# Common link targets in Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx

I have a lot of Sphinx pages which have the same links on them. Like those:

```
.. _CC-BY: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/
.. _MIT: http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
```

Currently, I have those two lines in every file that has a `MIT_` in it. Is it possible to have a central file in the project where I can put those link targets? That way, I could write `MIT_` anywhere and it would link to that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put your link definitions in [rst_epilog](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-rst_epilog) in conf.py:

```
rst_epilog = """
.. _CC-BY: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/
.. _MIT: http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
"""
```

Comment: **This is the way.** Note that [another StackOverflow answer provides an even better extension to this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61694897/2809027): rather than embed links directly in `rst_epilog` (which has a tendency to get out of hand *real* fast), instead have your `conf.py` open and read the contents of a `links.rst` file into this `rst_epilog` setting. `\o/`