# Hyperlinks with ReStructured Text

Tags: restructuredtext

I would like to write reusable hyperlinks the same way I do with Markdown:

```
You can also follow [this link][1] if you want. But if you really don't 
want to follow [my link][1], you could try [a better one][1].

[1]: http://google.com
```

Is there a way to do this with  ReST? When I try to convert the above code with Pandoc I get 3 times the same link:

```
You can also follow `this link`_ if you want. But if you really don’t
want to follow `my link`_, you could try `a better one`_.

.. _this link: http://google.com
.. _my link: http://google.com
.. _a better one: http://google.com
```

Comment: I'm stumped. The closest I think you can get is with `rst_epilog` as in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398548/common-link-targets-in-sphinx/18399137#18399137), but you want to change the text that gets hyperlinked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an embedded alias to replicate this functionality

```
You can also follow `this link <1_>`_ if you want. But if you really don't 
want to follow `my link <1_>`_, you could try `a better one <1_>`_.

.. _1: http://google.com
```

see [this great blog post](https://jwodder.github.io/kbits/posts/rst-hyperlinks/) for more hyperlink examples.

Answer (score 1):

To do this "the reStructured way", use the "most natural" name directly. In hyperlink references with a different link text use it as alias. The alias can be embedded or precede the hyperlink target definition:

```
If you really don't want to follow `my link`_, you
could try `the same with a different text <my link_>`_. 
However, you can also follow `this link`_ 
if you want --- it will lead to the same place.

.. _this link:
.. _my link: http://example.org
```